# Visualization of the timestamps in a call stack

Tags: c#, .net, performance, optimization, callstack

I'm trying to tune the performance of my application. And I'm curious what methods are taking the longest to process, and thus should be looked over for any optimization opportunities.

Are there any existing free tools that will help me visualize the call stack and how long each method is taking to complete? I'm thinking something that displays the call stack as a stacked bar graph or a [treemap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treemapping) so it's easy to see that **MethodA()** took 10 second to complete because it called **MethodB()** and **Method(C)** that took 3 and 7 seconds to complete.

Does something like this exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they are called performance profilers. Check out RedGate ANTS and JetBrains' dotTrace, not free but pretty cheap and way better than any free alternative I have seen.

Comment: I've seen those but I'm really looking for something that's free and simple. I found this free .NET profiler called EQATEC that look like exactly what I need.

http://www.eqatec.com/tools/profiler/guide

Answer (score 0):

Several profilers are available. I'm only familiar with one (the one included in Visual Studio Team Suite), but it's not free. I must say, it's been powerful/reliable enough that I've had no desire to try switching to another. The other one I've heard about is Red Gate's .NET profiler (also not free). Both of these have feature sets including, but definitely not limited to, what you're after. If this is for commercial application development, definitely check them out. :)

Answer (score 0):

The way this is measured is by either instrumentation or sampling within a profiler.

#### Instrumentation

Instrumentation does the rough equivalent of rewriting all your code to do the following:

```
public void Foo()
{
   //Code
}
```

into

```
public void Foo()
{
   InformTheProfilingCodeThatFooStarted();
   //Code
   InformTheProfilingCodeThatFooEnded();
}
```

Since the profiler knows when everything starts and stops it can managed a stack of when thisngs start and stop and supply this information later. Many allow you to do this at a line level (by doing much the same thing but instrumenting even more before each line.

This gets your 100% accurate information on the 'call graph' in your application but does so at the cost of: preventing inlining of methods and adding considerable overhead to each method call.

#### Sampling

An alternate approach is Sampling.

Instead of trying to get 100% accurate call graphs but with less than accurate actual *times* this approach instead works on the basis that, if it check on a regular basis what is going on in your app it can give you a good idea of how much time it sepnds in various functions without actually having to spend much effort working this out. Most sampling profilers know how to 'parse' the call stack when they interrupt the program so they can still give a reasonable idea of what is calling which function and how much time this seems to take but will not be able to tell you whether this was (say) 10 calls to Foo() which did ten calls to Bar() or one call to Foo() which was in the one call to Bar() which just happened to last so long it was sampled 10 times.

Both approaches have their pros and cons and solve different problems. In general the sampling method is the best one to start with first since it is less invasive and thus should give more accurate information on what is *taking time* which is often the most important first question before working out *why*.

I know of only one free sampling profiler for .net code which is the free redistributable profiler which is linked with the VS 2008 Team System release (but which can be downloaded separately). The resulting output cannot be easily viewed with anything but the (very expensive) Team System edition of Visual Studio.

Red Gate ANTS does not support sampling (at this time), Jet Brains (dotTrace) and MS Visual Studio Team System have profilers that support both styles. Which you prefer on a cost benefit basis is a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 0):

[This is the method I use.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux/378024#378024) If you have an IDE with a pause button it costs nothing and works very well.

What it tells you is roughly what % of wall-clock time is spent in each routine, and more precisely, in each statement. That is more important than the average duration of executing the routine or statement, because it automatically factors in the invocation count. By sampling wall-clock time it automatically includes CPU, IO, and other kinds of system time.

Even more importantly, if you look at the samples in which your routine is on the call stack, you can see not only what it is doing, but *why*. The reason that is important is that what you are really looking for is time being spent that could be replaced with something faster. Without the "why" information, you have to guess what that is.

BTW: This technique is little-known mainly because professors do not teach it (even if they know it) because they seldom have to work with monstrous software like we have in the real world, so they treat `gprof` as the foundation paradigm of profiling.

[Here's an example of using it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926266/performance-optimization-strategies-of-last-resort/927773#927773)

P.S. Expect the percents to add up to a lot more than 100%. The way to think about the percents is, if a statement or routine is on the stack X% of the time (as estimated from a small number of samples), that is roughly how much wall-clock time will shrink if the statement or routine can be made to take a lot less time.